# How do I remove the time from printpreview dialog?

Tags: vb.net, printing, datagrid, print-preview

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Drawing.Printing
Namespace Print
Public Class Form1

    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    Dim PrintC As PrinterClass
    Dim conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection

    Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=..\\db1.mdb"

    Dim sql As String = String.Empty
    Dim ds As DataSet

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        FillDataGrid()
        '//create printerclass object
        PrintC = New PrinterClass(PrintDocument1, dataGrid)
    End Sub

    Private Sub FillDataGrid()

        Try

            Dim dt As New DataTable
            Dim ds As New DataSet

            ds.Tables.Add(dt)
            Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter


            con.Open()
            da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * from klient ", con)

            da.Fill(dt)

            con.Close()

            dataGrid.DataSource = dt.DefaultView

            Dim dTable As DataTable
            For Each dTable In ds.Tables

                Dim dgStyle As DataGridTableStyle = New DataGridTableStyle
                dgStyle.MappingName = dTable.TableName
                dataGrid.TableStyles.Add(dgStyle)

            Next
            ' DataGrid settings
            dataGrid.CaptionText = "TE GJITHE KLIENTET"
            dataGrid.HeaderFont = New Font("Verdana", 12)
            dataGrid.TableStyles(0).GridColumnStyles(0).Width = 60
            dataGrid.TableStyles(0).GridColumnStyles(1).Width = 140
            dataGrid.TableStyles(0).GridColumnStyles(2).Width = 140
            dataGrid.TableStyles(0).GridColumnStyles(3).Width = 140
            dataGrid.TableStyles(0).GridColumnStyles(4).Width = 140
            dataGrid.TableStyles(0).GridColumnStyles(5).HeaderText = ""
            dataGrid.TableStyles(0).GridColumnStyles(5).Width = -1


        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
        'create printerclass object
        PrintC = New PrinterClass(PrintDocument1, dataGrid)

        PrintDocument1.Print()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPreview_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPreview.Click

        'create printerclass object
        PrintC = New PrinterClass(PrintDocument1, dataGrid)

        ''preview
        Dim ps As New PaperSize("A4", 840, 1150)
        ps.PaperName = PaperKind.A4
        PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ps

        PrintPreviewDialog1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        PrintPreviewDialog1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
        PrintPreviewDialog1.ClientSize = New Size(600, 600)

        PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()

    End Sub


    Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
        'print grid

        Dim morepages As Boolean = PrintC.Print(e.Graphics)
        If (morepages) Then

            e.HasMorePages = True
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
End Namespace
```

This is how data looks in DataGrid (that's perfect)...

[image]

and here is how it looks when I click PrintPreview. (I don't want the time to appear there, the "12:00:00" part. in database the date is stored as Short Date (10-Dec-12)

[image]

Can somebody suggest a way around that?

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Printing
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Data
Namespace Print
Public Class PrinterClass
    '//clone of Datagrid
    Dim PrintGrid As Grid

    '//printdocument for initial printer settings
    Private PrintDoc As PrintDocument

    '//defines whether the grid is ordered right to left
    Private bRightToLeft As Boolean

    '//Current Top
    Private CurrentY As Single = 0

    '//Current Left
    Private CurrentX As Single = 0

    '//CurrentRow to print
    Private CurrentRow As Integer = 0

    '//Page Counter
    Public PageCounter As Integer = 0

    '/// <summary>
    '/// Constructor Class
    '/// </summary>
    '/// <param name="pdocument"></param>
    '/// <param name="dgrid"></param>
    Public Sub New(ByVal pdocument As PrintDocument, ByVal dgrid As DataGrid)
        'MyBase.new()

        PrintGrid = New Grid(dgrid)
        PrintDoc = pdocument

        '//The grid columns are right to left
        bRightToLeft = dgrid.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes

        '//init CurrentX and CurrentY
        CurrentY = pdocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top
        CurrentX = pdocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left


    End Sub

    Public Function Print(ByVal g As Graphics, ByRef currentX As Single, ByRef currentY As Single) As Boolean

        '//use predefined area
        currentX = currentX
        currentY = currentY

        PrintHeaders(g)

        Dim Morepages As Boolean = PrintDataGrid(g)

        currentY = currentY
        currentX = currentX

        Return Morepages


    End Function

    Public Function Print(ByVal g As Graphics) As Boolean

        CurrentX = PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left
        CurrentY = PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top
        PrintHeaders(g)
        Return PrintDataGrid(g)
    End Function

    '/// <summary>
    '/// Print the Grid Headers
    '/// </summary>
    '/// <param name="g"></param>
    Private Sub PrintHeaders(ByVal g As Graphics)

        Dim sf As StringFormat = New StringFormat

        '//if we want to print the grid right to left
        If (bRightToLeft) Then

            CurrentX = PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width - PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right
            sf.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft
        Else
            CurrentX = PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left
        End If
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To PrintGrid.Columns - 1

            '//set header alignment
            Select Case (CType(PrintGrid.Headers.GetValue(i), Header).Alignment)
                Case HorizontalAlignment.Left 'left 
                    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
                Case HorizontalAlignment.Center
                    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
                Case HorizontalAlignment.Right
                    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
            End Select


            '//advance X according to order
            If (bRightToLeft) Then


                '//draw the cell bounds (lines) and back color
                g.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(PrintGrid.HeaderBackColor), CurrentX - PrintGrid.Headers(i).Width, CurrentY, PrintGrid.Headers(i).Width, PrintGrid.Headers(i).Height)
                g.DrawRectangle(New Pen(PrintGrid.LineColor), CurrentX - PrintGrid.Headers(i).Width, CurrentY, PrintGrid.Headers(i).Width, PrintGrid.Headers(i).Height)

                '//draw the cell text
                g.DrawString(PrintGrid.Headers(i).CText, PrintGrid.Headers(i).Font, New SolidBrush(PrintGrid.HeaderForeColor), New RectangleF(CurrentX - PrintGrid.Headers(i).Width, CurrentY, PrintGrid.Headers(i).Width, PrintGrid.Headers(i).Height), sf)
                '//next cell
                CurrentX -= PrintGrid.Headers(i).Width
            Else
                '//draw the cell bounds (lines) and back color
                g.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(PrintGrid.HeaderBackColor), CurrentX, CurrentY, PrintGrid.Headers(i).Width, PrintGrid.Headers(i).Height)
                g.DrawRectangle(New Pen(PrintGrid.LineColor), CurrentX, CurrentY, PrintGrid.Headers(i).Width, PrintGrid.Headers(i).Height)


                '//draw the cell text
                g.DrawString(PrintGrid.Headers(i).CText, PrintGrid.Headers(i).Font, New SolidBrush(PrintGrid.HeaderForeColor), New RectangleF(CurrentX, CurrentY, PrintGrid.Headers(i).Width, PrintGrid.Headers(i).Height), sf)

                '//next cell
                CurrentX += PrintGrid.Headers(i).Width
            End If
        Next

        '//reset to beginning
        If (bRightToLeft) Then
            '//right align
            CurrentX = PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width - PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right
        Else
            '//left align
            CurrentX = PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left
        End If

        '//advance to next row
        CurrentY = CurrentY + CType(PrintGrid.Headers.GetValue(0), Header).Height

    End Sub



    Private Function PrintDataGrid(ByVal g As Graphics) As Boolean
        Dim sf As StringFormat = New StringFormat
        PageCounter = PageCounter + 1

        '//if we want to print the grid right to left
        If (bRightToLeft) Then
            CurrentX = PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width - PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right
            sf.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft
        Else
            CurrentX = PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left
        End If
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = CurrentRow To PrintGrid.Rows - 1
            Dim j As Integer
            For j = 0 To PrintGrid.Columns - 1

                '//set cell alignment
                Select Case (PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Alignment)
                    '//left
                Case HorizontalAlignment.Left
                        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near

                    Case HorizontalAlignment.Center
                        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center


                        '//right
                    Case HorizontalAlignment.Right
                        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far

                End Select

                '//advance X according to order
                If (bRightToLeft) Then
                    '//draw the cell bounds (lines) and back color
                    g.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(PrintGrid.BackColor), CurrentX - PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Width, CurrentY, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Width, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Height)
                    g.DrawRectangle(New Pen(PrintGrid.LineColor), CurrentX - PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Width, CurrentY, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Width, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Height)

                    '//draw the cell text
                    g.DrawString(PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).CText, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Font, New SolidBrush(PrintGrid.ForeColor), New RectangleF(CurrentX - PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Width, CurrentY, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Width, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Height), sf)

                    '//next cell
                    CurrentX -= PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Width
                Else
                    '//draw the cell bounds (lines) and back color
                    g.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(PrintGrid.BackColor), CurrentX, CurrentY, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Width, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Height)
                    g.DrawRectangle(New Pen(PrintGrid.LineColor), CurrentX, CurrentY, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Width, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Height)
                    '//draw the cell text
                    '//Draw text by alignment
                    g.DrawString(PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).CText, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Font, New SolidBrush(PrintGrid.ForeColor), New RectangleF(CurrentX, CurrentY, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Width, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Height), sf)

                    '//next cell
                    CurrentX += PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Width
                End If


            Next

            '//reset to beginning
            If (bRightToLeft) Then
                '//right align
                CurrentX = PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width - PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right
            Else
                '//left align
                CurrentX = PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left
            End If

            '//advance to next row
            CurrentY += PrintGrid.Cell(i, 0).Height
            CurrentRow += 1
            '//if we are beyond the page margin (bottom) then we need another page,
            '//return true
            If (CurrentY > PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height - PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom) Then

                Return True
            End If
        Next
        Return False

    End Function
End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Clearly the problem is located in "PrinterClass".  You didn't post its code so you probably didn't write it nor realized it mattered.  The diagnostic is that it uses the default formatting for a DateTime, which of course includes the time.

Comment: thanks @Hans I just added the class above. You're right, I didn't write it myself and it's a little too advanced  for my current level..

Comment: Well, never use code you don't understand.  If you expect anybody to rewrite it for you then you posted to the wrong web site.

Comment: It's calling `Grid.Cell.CText`, but you haven't showed the code for `Grid`, so we can only guess at the type of its `Cell` property.  Presumably it's a custom class and `CText` is a property that is supposed to return the cell text.  Presumably the problem is in that `CText` property.  Use your debugger, trace into, and find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Albo,

I think it might be useful to set a breakpoint at

```
 '//draw the cell text
 g.DrawString(PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).CText, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Font, New SolidBrush(PrintGrid.ForeColor), New RectangleF(CurrentX - PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Width, CurrentY, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Width, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Height), sf)
```

To see exactly what's going on. Without running such a breakpoint, and from this resource [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), my first guess might be something like this:

```
If j = PrintGrid.Columns - 1 Then
    Dim pattern As String = "MM-dd-yy"
    If DateTime.TryParseExact(PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).CText, pattern, Nothing, DateTimeStyles.None, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).CText) Then
    g.DrawString(PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).CText, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Font, New SolidBrush(PrintGrid.ForeColor), New RectangleF(CurrentX - PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Width, CurrentY, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Width, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Height), sf)
Else
     g.DrawString(PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).CText, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Font, New SolidBrush(PrintGrid.ForeColor), New RectangleF(CurrentX - PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Width, CurrentY, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Width, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Height), sf)
End If
```

This attempts to parse the text of the column (in your case, the PrintGrid.Columns - 1th cell) as a date, if it succeeds, then it puts the newly formatted text back into the column before it sends it to the print sub. I highly doubt this code would work as-is, but with some debugging and application of correct string to datetime formatting...I think this is the right direction.

Comment: thanks so much buddy, you got me on track with your answer and then I solved it in another way, using string Split :) I posted my solution below if anyone else finds it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Based in the answer @SacredFaith posted, I solved the problem a little bit differently.
Here is the solution using string split:

```
                    '//Draw text by alignment
                    ' g.DrawString(PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).CText, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Font, New SolidBrush(PrintGrid.ForeColor), New RectangleF(CurrentX, CurrentY, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Width, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Height), sf)

                    If j = 3 Or j = 4 Then
                        Dim st As String = PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).CText.ToString
                        Dim t As Array = st.Split(" ")
                        g.DrawString(t(0), PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Font, New SolidBrush(PrintGrid.ForeColor), New RectangleF(CurrentX, CurrentY, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Width, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Height), sf)
                    Else
                        g.DrawString(PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).CText, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Font, New SolidBrush(PrintGrid.ForeColor), New RectangleF(CurrentX, CurrentY, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Width, PrintGrid.Cell(i, j).Height), sf)
                    End If
```